# asp net mvc on 500 error, page rendering unicode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, webforms

I have a ASP.NET Web Form site, in which I blended ASP.NET MVC so now we have ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC both on this site

If I have a error on Web Forms page it shows regular yellow error page
But When I am accessing MVC page and it throws 500 error, it renders all as this Unicode characters.

How can I fix this?

��{sڸ��3����.�%晤�ܼz�L�f�l;w�N*l�5�W�I��~�{�d��!}m�Ild�u$���/�o���{~Bz��5�?kDW�F�Q'��ߕ�<�|G����>W�͈z��h��9��ćk�H �5 fX�t������e�j���W�W����z��6��_6H!9\��=��ΐ|�����ް�� ��t��[o������E�z�I����.��m�qQk{��\��$�KM�S�u�-Ń����Nʺ�6���)�������� ��IVG$Ab�� ��`S�q_r�ʍ����vJL�ȟq�ˀ�,I��)j�z@������ N�\�m��\(F��c>CX~I O�����3+v��fsA�������LHxD�D��'{0!8��\��J�~�����T����m{`2�9�&P�:�  �Hf��p _z@�>a����R"m��O�1��静P5�S��6ɗ��u�VQ`�Aߎ�ok�����m�UlK;���n ��G߂%����aR��e���#[���-�z��L�B�Ţ�:W��ڄ�kP���� P�o6NK�K&��D����o���Ax���d5z�H�_*�E0L�K�A���`l�Q:3z�&i��'S��*����q�.F�{�7�K�<9e ����?�g�^��%����y"�d��k��䘁���̊F��<�I�c�y�;؝��3�mHL'N(`r�c�١y�� ��y��D�?C&�E�=F%��$�nR��$J�20 �s��`���h��ʰ���@��1�.�?�@�f�f�*��4�OFjÊ�zҨ~9����� ���p٨g�,��l������2�V�4��Q��ځ�mo4'G�Ab�Q�;���ڰـ٨ex �T*;��y�aj�s���lu�bN%��\�{��r6G�wG�aΛ6�C 5�>/kI9T@���A�}S�Aq׽�����s�ˏ�0D����b�Q�;]R�|���������+�OY�1�rwd�/wVK3��l�įg��Ǻ��� �!��'O�7x�,c ��a��޴� ��p8n�lZW��+Un��(��逈�UHs%�N;�0�R�0}bD�  FbfJ������#W ��h҃.L�kX>*�i����V*vmԄ�pLe�ͩp�[��c8������a(��R��]׾~���0��C˖(��-���O��8/O�K�f�0�|����2�����<�Q3�RX�O���U�C�5n�T���ɫз?���}��$�W��ogx˚��Th��R����o>�8F�0+�����?Z֫�/f�.T   �y��Y9n���-+�,����F �ގѣ��Co��=��<.CX��d����|$ढ़r����l`[6ϙ�t��Bِ��F��E{�5A;�L�R5���`�0ǰ�w<����7�+jɓֱ��S1��份��xL�pn�[�\��/&����N5���*����,qq5:d�1 �е'�Dʤ �0�on*{���v�d�)B���H��X!f}�v����D1�#E��6��qL�S�:���|��.��d������A�����a��3v��`|���HY�c�l����݁�n�ed��a�Ӽ�Ã�;`�ϴ���l�H;�778O=:<�����<�k'�ݽ�4�Je:&��6�9�登4G+-p��~̀KXen�fй�(�ӽ�dk7�,O�4��=��ɽ:7�ݳ��-�Gp��͚���$�]�k����]�,f�w�u�3���v��/���ɑ�s��t{�M��K>Zs�upk.�®l͹"�g�T�ZSdAf���Nu�(�6�M۰G�0e��{�79 eN�K?ΜHX�M�6W���PK墄�Ј�/�2M����sG��]�+�Dz�ޏ�/΅���HB�&�^���.����S���#�n�}N���=�� :��)r������v�Z��L�9j�L�%taq\� b�('TQ�[\�vV���e�^��]6��4��s�#���n�)�ݴ|������BH�Y�Ĕ`\y}$%��?ހ��5��Zx�   X�@mvu�?d*�ܓ�|����vo�׽�E���g�M #ְ/J��}��3�R�gq������:�%�`|�:K���ǃ�uUT�b:J݉]п�@�Yf$���*�w0�O�k���˷��v;u��*�Q�G�@�w��`�ݘHc����jZ2ʨp��3u/�H�v.��"m�QN|�� ��b]iwN%�Z�T�{��=U랪uOպ%�uh���I��T,H���x��d������j�2�JM�F���$1�6�`t�}A�"Y���s�|m�*�o#��A��u����E������D�t�ڂK�Q�zsrE^!JA"$V�ZE�R��������Əv�R��U�ak�o#tk��/�x�*��H���"̈́����(�W��2�qAXQL��yR1��{iY#t���h**����El�'pQ����'7�5�*�_�踖x��:���ܒ���]x�:#�0��XԌ�H�#Ls������8#E�21 2P;�{�Lk��%v��u�/�uZ�˥��v�S�Q�eͼ��<��~�XYZ�Ħ�1]�i>��-{�*�X�^��͛�j��~���W�����44R�8͇�p~:�V湟��U+���?�����?���j�4\l���-�N�B�=��Ռ@UW=WF�<�� �ǟh�Ʉ�X��3�����Oֵ�MC8J�/�:n7��S���%&�\�?k�3�!� ��K�i�R�~I����x��l�o���t�p���'�"���s����0��bт;��}2��e(%-����<��NV

I do have META tag in my layout page

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error page is served as `gziped` content by your webserver but you are missing the `Content-Encoding` response header to indicate to the user agent that he needs to decompress the stream before displaying it.

Try clearing response filters in your `Application_Error` method in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Filter = null;
    ...
}
```

Rick Strahl wrote a [`very detailed blog post`](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats) about what is happening here.

Comment: That helped. Thanks